# How does a bounty draw more attention to your question?

Tags: support, bounty, interesting-page, featured-page

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29443769/replace-count-in-innodb-query-for-optimization) for which I never received a correct answer. I recently added a bounty to the question but since have not seen any new views.

After spending reputation points, I was expecting the question to move back to the top of the interesting tab as well as the featured tab however it is at the top of neither.

- After adding a bounty, is the question ordered in the featured list based on the original date it was asked?
- Should the question be added to the interesting list?

Based on what I am seeing, it's not worth the reputation to start a bounty.

**EDIT :**
Just found my question in the featured list, it's on the last page at the bottom!

So the answer to the first question is that SO does in fact order your question on the featured list based on the date it was asked, NOT when you place a bounty on it. It was also not added to the interesting list.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> So, the answer to the first question is that SO does in fact order your question on the featured list based on the date it was asked. NOT when you place a bounty on it.

Incorrect. The ordering is based on when you place your bounty but in the opposite order of what you assume: newest bounties are added at the end. This has as effect that the ones about to expire are shown at the very front and those recently placed are at the very end.

> Should the question move to the top of the interesting list?

Should it? I don't see any arguments pro/contra in your question.

Note that your bounty is placed just now so don't expect a bunch of views and answers within minutes -- there's a reason you needed a bounty in the first place.

Furthermore: a bounty has the same effect as an edit as far as I know: you will get bumped to the interesting tab. This might take a few minutes and it might not be at the very top but it will get there. Keep in mind that that tab is different for everyone.

Comment: As I thought more about it, I came to the same conclusion as you stated about it being at the end. It makes sense now. But, it never did show up on the interesting tab (for me anyway) although the question contains my favorite tags, which I feel it should because personally that is the only place I look.